# A problem occurred configuring project ':path_provider'

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle

I have been facing this error for quite some time now and I am having no luck solving it. I am on Flutter version `2.2.1` and whenever I try to run my project I receive the following error:

```
[Fatal Error] auto-parent-3.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.  
[Fatal Error] google-1.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.       
[Fatal Error] google-1.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.       
                                                                        
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':path_provider'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':path_provider:classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.5.2.
     Required by:
         project :path_provider > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.6.0
      > Could not resolve com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.5.2.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/auto/value/auto-value/1.5.2/auto-value-1.5.2.pom
            > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:3.          
               > Could not resolve com.google.auto:auto-parent:3.       
                  > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/auto/auto-parent/3/auto-parent-3.pom
                     > Content is not allowed in prolog.                
   > Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.4.0.         
     Required by:                                                       
         project :path_provider > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.6.0
         project :path_provider > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.3.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.3.0
         project :path_provider > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.3.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:26.3.0         project :path_provider > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.3.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:26.3.0
         project :path_provider > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.6.0 > com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:0.3.1
      > Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.4.0.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/3.4.0/protobuf-java-3.4.0.pom
            > Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-parent:3.4.0.
               > Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-parent:3.4.0.
                  > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-parent/3.4.0/protobuf-parent-3.4.0.pom
                     > Could not resolve com.google:google:1.
                        > Could not resolve com.google:google:1.
                           > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/google/1/google-1.pom
                              > Content is not allowed in prolog.
   > Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.4.0.
     Required by:
         project :path_provider > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.6.0
      > Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.4.0. 
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java-util/3.4.0/protobuf-java-util-3.4.0.pom
            > Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-parent:3.4.0.
                  > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-parent/3.4.0/protobuf-parent-3.4.0.pom
                     > Could not resolve com.google:google:1.
                        > Could not resolve com.google:google:1.
                           > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/google/1/google-1.pom
                              > Content is not allowed in prolog.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':path_provider' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 21s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                       218.9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I am unable to figure out why this error is occurring.
This is the output when I run `flutter doctor -v`:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1052], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.2.1 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 02c026b03c (3 weeks ago), 2021-05-27 12:24:44 -0700
    • Engine revision 0fdb562ac8
    • Dart version 2.13.1

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Abhinav\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[!] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.9.4)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.9.31205.134
    X Visual Studio is missing necessary components. Please re-run the Visual Studio installer for the "Desktop development with C++" workload, and include these
      components:
        MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools
         - If there are multiple build tool versions available, install the latest
        C++ CMake tools for Windows
        Windows 10 SDK

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)

[√] VS Code (version 1.57.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Abhinav\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.23.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • Redmi Note 8 Pro (mobile) • 8livzdlvnnsoy5qw • android-arm64  • Android 10 (API 29)
    • Windows (desktop)         • windows          • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1052]
    • Chrome (web)              • chrome           • web-javascript • Google Chrome 91.0.4472.101
    • Edge (web)                • edge             • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 90.0.818.62

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

This is my `pubspec.yaml` file:

```yaml
name: new_registreation1
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: "none" # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.11.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  pinput: ^1.2.0
  flutter_swiper: ^1.1.6
  syncfusion_flutter_sliders: ^19.1.67-beta
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  google_fonts: ^2.0.0-nullsafety.0
  flutter_svg: ^0.22.0
  flutter_signin_button: ^2.0.0
  pin_code_fields: ^7.2.0
  percent_indicator: ^3.0.1
  flutter_range_slider: ^1.5.0
  palette_generator: ^0.3.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/image1.svg
    - assets/image2.svg
    - assets/image3.svg
    - assets/image4.svg
    - assets/image5.svg
    - assets/image6.svg
    - assets/image7.svg
    - assets/image8.svg
    - assets/image9.svg
    - assets/image10.svg
    - assets/image11.svg
    - assets/image12.svg
    - assets/image13.svg
    - assets/image14.svg
    - assets/back.png
    - assets/ChatsCircle.png
    - assets/next.png
    - assets/heart.png
    - assets/profileIcon.png
    - assets/refresh.png
    - assets/Spotify Icon.png
    - assets/google_icon.svg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

I will attach more outputs if needed.

Comment: there are multiple way to fix this. Run pub outdated and check which dependency suits better for project. Another is downgrade the current version and check it. But running pub outdated will help you out.

Comment: I will try it out. Thanks

Comment: @Venky I tried out your fix but none of them worked for me. I tried flutter downgrade as well but it shows that version 2.2.0 was the last stable version, which still shows the same error.